# Cartesian to polar

Tags: polar-coordinates

Would this equation be able to convert to polar coordinates? And then could we solve for r?

$$y=\sqrt[x] {\frac 13\left(1^x+2^x+3^x\right)}$$

Comment: Well, you can convert it to polar coordinate by replace $y$ with $r \cos \theta$, $x$ with $r\cos \theta$ and $\sqrt[x]{stuff}$ with $stuff^{\frac 1{r\cos \theta}}$.  That's just organ grinding.  Solving it... that'd be a nightmare... (although it's no picnic in cartesian either).

Comment: i wish to solve for r... yes that's why i am asking here... You guys are professionals